# PHP CLI version not getting updated

Tags: php, php-cli

I have updated the PHP Version to `5.6.9-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+2` but on command line when I type `php - v`, it shows

```
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2014 14:53:07) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Why is it so?
How can I resolve this?

Comment: How did you upgrade?

Comment: using this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html

Comment: What is your ubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu version is 15.04

Comment: Please check the answer

Comment: Uninstall the manually installed php from sources located in /usr/local ...

Answer (score 0):

The [link provided by you above](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html) for Ubuntu 14* and 12* and they have no repository for Ubuntu 15.04 so please to install PHP5.6 in Ubuntu 15.04 add this repositoy:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5
```

Now check your version with `php5 -v`

Comment: Now I tried php5  -v then it shows                                                                   PHP 5.6.9-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+2 (cli) (built: May 24 2015 15:44:56) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies  but while typing php -v it shows as previous

Comment: I am running the  command                                                               composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"                                                             and this is giving the error                                                           guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.3 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.29) does not satisfy that requirement.  It is not picking up the new php5-cli

Comment: Please do it as in my answer, you can have it running smoothly your link doesn;t work for 15.04